# Log4j does not create the logfile

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I want to use the unusuable log4J for logfiles in a java maven application. But the logfile is not created.

This is my a part of my .pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my log4j.properties file (under src/main/resources):

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=E:\\Test\\logfile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

In my main method:

```
log.debug("debug");
log.info("info");
log.warn("warn");
log.error("error");
```

The log messages are in the console log, but the logfile has not been created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your `pom.xml`  is not correct. it has to be `<dependency>` in the first line. (missing >)

Apart from that, your `log4j.properties` should do the work, I tried it and it writes a log-file.

How do you create the Logger instance `log`?
Do you have writing access to `E:\\Test\\logfile.log`?

Comment: Hi that dependency is a typo only here. I have corrected the question. Yes I have write access to the path E:\\Test\\logfile.log

Comment: and how do you create the `log`instance? Maybe you use false import statement there, it has to be `org.apache.log4j.Logger`

Comment: I am using lombok's @Log4J annotation. That works in simmilar projects as well

Comment: yes, with lombok's `Log4J` annotation I can log also to file with your  log4j.properties, so seems correct.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it is a logback.config in my single depency that overwrites my configuration.